# Find the position of a word in a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a JS script and I want to get the position of a word in a text by clicking on it. For example:

> This is my paragraph and I want to get the word ***paragraph*** of
>   this text.

Let's assume that I am clicking on the ***paragraph*** that appears for second time in this text. The result should be 12 as it's the 12th word. How could I do that?

So far I can double click on a word and get it but I also need its position.

```
 <script> $(document).ready(function() {

        var p = $('p');
        p.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });

        p.dblclick(function(e) {
            var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
            var word = $.trim(range.toString());
            if(word != '') {
                alert(word);
            }
            range.collapse();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

    });</script>

    <p>This is my paragraph and I want to get the word paragraph of this text.</p>
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The nearest similar job would be done by [highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text). When you click the `<p>`, you get the tag element in the whole, not its content, so is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `anchorOffset` to determine the index of the first character of your selection (thanks @tech2017).

After that, it's a matter of counting how many words come before this index.

The easiest way to count words, is counting the whitespace instead. We'll split on `\s+` to make sure we [account for multiple spaces, newlines and more.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)

**Note:** I do not know how well this works in all browsers. Make sure to test!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var p = $('p');
  p.css({
    cursor: 'pointer'
  });

  p.dblclick(function(e) {
    var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
    var word = $.trim(range.toString());
    if (word != '') {
      // Count words
      var charIdx = range.anchorOffset;
      var countStr = range.anchorNode.textContent.substr(0, charIdx);
      var wordNumber = (countStr === "") ? 1 : countStr.trim().split(/\s+/).length + 1;
      alert(wordNumber);
    }
    //range.collapse();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is my paragraph and I want to get the word paragraph of this text.</p>
```

Comment: Two observations: 1) Both **This** and **is** are denoted with index 1, and 2) the period at the end of the sentence has it's own index, 15.

Comment: Concering the dot, interesting observation. Depends on what the OP wants but you could remove all non-alphanumerical and non-whitespace characters pre-counting.

Comment: I think it that is the most efficient way to do it. Thanks @Kokos

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this?

```js
var p = $('#text');
var text = p.html();

// wrap each word into custom tag with data-i attribute as index
p.html(text.split(' ').map(function(word,index){

  return `<w-d data-i='${index+1}'>${word}</w-d>`

}).join(' '))

// bind actions
$('w-d').click(function(){

  var index = $(this).attr('data-i');
  alert(index)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Click on my words.</p>
```

Comment: I would not recommend splitting up all your text into separate divs with 
separate event handlers when it is not necessary :).

Comment: Kokos do you have an idea how this can be done properly?im curious anyway.

Comment: Yes, see below!

Comment: Yes i have tried your solution and it works exelent,OP should use your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anchorOffset` to get the position of the selected text (index 0 based).
Check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/8945/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var p = $('p');
  p.css({
    cursor: 'pointer'
  });

  p.dblclick(function(e) {
    var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
    var word = $.trim(range.toString());
    if (word != '') {
      alert(word);
      var temp = range.anchorOffset;
      alert(temp);
    }
    //range.collapse();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is my paragraph and I want to get the word paragraph of this text.</p>
```

Comment: That's pretty close but not what exaclty I am looking for, because it is counting characters instead of words

Answer (score -2):

You have to count the Whitespace character and then add 1 to the result.

Example: This***1***is***2***my***3***paragraph***4***and***5***I***6***want***7***to***8***get***9***the***10***word***11***paragraph of this text.

Comment: This is not generic solution @Hakim